# Run automatically Script when GitHub Issue has been closed

Tags: python, github

I would like to run automatically a (python) Script, when a GitHub Issue has been closen.
The Script should send another user an message via a Chatbot, so it need to be a custom script, where i can manipulate the data etc.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be [GitHub Actions's `issues` trigger](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#issues):

```
on:
  issues:
    types: [closed]
jobs:
  Run:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.9
      - run: python ...
```

Comment: Thanks, didnt know GitHub actions before!